# I've tried everything. How to get my Header and Footer divs to stack on top of my Container div?

Tags: css, flexbox, z-index

I want my Header and Footer divs to float above my central Container div to provide the illusion of a continuing design. Instead, my Container floats above them both. How can I fix this? I've tried transforms, setting position and adding z-index. What am I doing wrong?

[Here's my CodePen with the code in it.](https://codepen.io/ZephyrBrightmoon/pen/xxqedmY)

```css
:root {
    --cpink: #FEA3FF;
    --cgrey: #48494B;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
/*  overflow-x: hidden; */
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    font: 20px Garamond;
    color: WHITE;
}

html::before {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    content:"";
    box-shadow: 0 0 80px 80px BLACK inset;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.preload * {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -ms-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;
}

img {
    border-style: none;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active, a:focus
{
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;

}

a:link {
    color: var(--cpink);
}

a:visited {
    color: #FF6B87;
}

a:hover {
    color: #FFD1DA;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Garamond';
    src: url('Garamond.eot');
    src: url('Garamond.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('Garamond.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('Garamond.woff') format('woff'),
        url('Garamond.svg#Garamond') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Garamond';
    src: url('Garamond-Bold.eot');
    src: url('Garamond-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('Garamond-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('Garamond-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('Garamond-Bold.svg#Garamond-Bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

p {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.title {
    display: block;
    color: WHITE;
    font-family: 'Porcelain', cursive;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 6%;
    clear: left;
}

/* Flexbox code */

header, footer {
  position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

header {
    background: BLACK url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/images/bg/WallPanelsHd.png') top left no-repeat;
    background-position: 49.5% 0;
    background-size: 130%;
    height: 20%;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: visible;
}

#container {
    background: BLACK url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/images/bg/WallPanelsMn.png');
    background-position: 49.5% 0;
    background-size: 130%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

article {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
    height: -moz-fit-content,
    fit-content;
    max-width: 40%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: TRANSPARENT;
}

nav, aside {
    min-width: 13%;
    background-color: TRANSPARENT;
}

nav {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
    padding: 0 20px 0 13%;
}

.nav2 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
    background-color: TRANSPARENT;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.menu {
    
    color: BLACK;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #fbbc93,
                 3px 3px 3px #fbbc93,
                 -3px 3px 3px #fbbc93,
                 3px -3px 3px #fbbc93,
                 -3px -3px 3px #fbbc93; 
}

.menuselect {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px WHITE,
                 -1px 1px 1px WHITE,
                 1px -1px 1px WHITE,
                 -1px -1px 1px WHITE,
                 3px 3px 3px #acace6,
                 -3px 3px 3px #acace6,
                 3px -3px 3px #acace6,
                 -3px -3px 3px #acace6;
}

aside {
    background: TRANSPARENT;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -ms-flex-order: 3;
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
    height: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

footer {
    background: BLACK url('http://www.cafenocturne.com/images/bg/WallPanelsFt.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 49.5% 0;
    background-size: 130%;
    height: 20%;
    min-height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: WHITE;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<body class="preload">
        <header>
            <span class="title">Welcome</span><br><br>
        </header>
    <div id="container">
        <nav>
        <div tabindex="1" class="menu menuselect">Home</div>
            <a href="intro.html"><div tabindex="2" class="menu">Introduction</div></a>
            <a href="staff.html"><div tabindex="3" class="menu">Staff</div></a>
            <a href="events.html" tabindex="4"><div class="menu">Special Events</div></a>
            <a href="AfterDark.html" tabindex="5"><div class="menu">After Dark</div></a>
            <a href="ConInfo.html" tabindex="6"><div class="menu">Convention Info</div></a>
            <a href="FanCorner.html" tabindex="7"><div class="menu">Fan Corner</div></a>
            <a href="faq.html" tabindex="8"><div class="menu">F A Q</div></a>
            <a href="contact.html" tabindex="9"><div class="menu">Contact Us</div></a>
        </nav>
            <article>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu dolor eu dolor varius sagittis sit amet in lectus. Curabitur mollis diam at feugiat cursus. Vestibulum et ex aliquet, fermentum risus in, volutpat purus. Aenean commodo non lectus in ultricies. Phasellus gravida odio arcu, at vulputate quam congue sed. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed et enim eget arcu convallis vestibulum. Quisque condimentum, felis sed porttitor pretium, mauris orci vulputate metus, commodo auctor nisl lorem vitae nibh. Sed lacinia ornare enim id sagittis. Vivamus finibus non sapien eget feugiat. Integer id varius tortor, et volutpat sapien. Phasellus ultricies fermentum ligula. Quisque ornare tincidunt efficitur.</p>
            </article>
        <aside>
            <div class="fadelinks">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://www.cafenocturne.com/images/PicSoon1.jpg"></a>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </div>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
```

Comment: Did you try giving a z-index of 1000 to both your header and footer?

Comment: Yes. It didn't help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try `position: sticky` for both the `header` and `footer`

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work.